# Как поймать клик с помощью event.target в popup.js и передать его content.js

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Есть расширение для хрома, которое обрабатывает все цвета на открытой вкладке и выводит их в popup, например вот так — rgb(192, 72, 72) и так далее.

Есть файлы:

1. popup.html
2. popup.js
3. popup.css
4. content.js
5. manifest.json

Поставил addEvenListener в popup.js, попап и выводит у себя клик в консоли, но мне нужно этот же клик передавать в content.js.

**popup.js:**

```
 list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  let target = e.target;
  console.log(target);

  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, tabs => {
    let currentTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTab.id, target);
  });
});
```

[image: popup.js]

**content.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
console.log(request); 

});
```

В content.js выводит объект:

[image: content.js]

Как сделать так, чтобы клик внутри попапа отображался в контент-скрипте?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging):

> A message can contain any valid JSON object (null, boolean, number, string, array, or object).

*Сообщение может содержать любой валидный JSON (null, boolean, number, string, array, или object)*

В вашем случае вы пытаетесь передать DOM элемент, который не является валидным типо данных для системы сообщений.

Полагаю вам стоит передавать значение этого элемента или некий кастомный JSON. В остальном ваш код рабочий.